# Empty project with docker supper in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to start an empty project which I've created in Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Core 1.1) with docker support.

But when I run an app, the chrome run and I have a message "Your application is starting..." and that's all.

When I create an app without docker support everything works fine.

Maybe should I somehow run docker firstly?

Comment: possibly something went wrong with docker? have you tried to see if the containers are running? `docker ps` to see the containers running and `docker logs [containerName]` to see its logs. Maybe it fails to startup or something and vs2017 is not expecting it to crash this early? (could you update your question with the data you see when executing these commands, and also post the docker file)